# Open safari with subprocess.runl()

Tags: macos, python-3.x

On MacOs, an app can be easily opened by

```
In [67]: os.system('open -a safari')
Out[67]: 0
```

According to [17.5. subprocess — Subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html),
`os.system` is deprecated.

So I tried `subprocess.call()`

```
In [68]: subprocess.call('open -a safari')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'open -a safari'
In [70]: subprocess.run('open -a opera')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'open -a opera'
```

How to enable `subprocess.call` execute instruction?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the errors briefly, I think that if you take out the "open" part of the code, and leave it as `-a safari`. It might work.